# If a function is bounded and the variable is bounded, is the function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose you have a function $f:C\to \mathbb R$ where $C$ is closed and bounded interval and $f$ is bounded.  Does that mean $f$ is continuous?  I know the other way around (if $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded) is true, but not this way.

Thanks!

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 6):

Nope!  Consider $f(x): [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $0 \leq x < 1/2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $1/2 \leq x \leq 1$.

Then the image of $f$ is $\{0,1\}$ which is a bounded set, and the domain is bounded, but $f$ has a discontinuity at $x = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That explains is so much better than my text!

Comment: Or, for a much worse counterexample, consider the Dirichlet's function.